# Using JSCH to SSH into server and run df command, but output just displays the command over and over

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, solaris-10

Here is my code. I am trying to SSH into a list of servers and get the disk space information from all of them by using the 'df' command.

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.*;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SSHClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSchException, IOException, InterruptedException{
        for(String arg : args){
            getDiskSpace(arg);
        }
    }
    public static void getDiskSpace(String host) throws JSchException, IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(host);
        String endLineStr = ">";
        String user = "";
        String password = ""; 
        int port = 22;

        JSch shell = new JSch();

        // get a new session  
        Session session = shell.getSession(user, host, port);

        // set user password and connect to a channel
        session.setUserInfo(new SSHUserInfo(password));
        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", 
                "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
        session.connect();
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("shell");
        channel.connect();

        DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(channel.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(channel.getOutputStream());

        while(dataIn.readLine().length()!=1)

        // send dk command to the server
        dataOut.writeBytes("df -k\r\n");
        dataOut.flush();

        // and print the response
        dataIn.readLine();
        String line = dataIn.readLine();
        while(!line.endsWith(endLineStr) && !line.endsWith(endLineStr+(Character.toString((char) 0)))) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = dataIn.readLine();
        }
        dataIn.close();
        dataOut.close();
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
        System.out.println("_______________________________________________________________________\n\n\n");
    }

    // this class implements jsch UserInfo interface for passing password to the session
    static class SSHUserInfo implements UserInfo {
        private String password;

        SSHUserInfo(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getPassphrase() {
            return null;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public boolean promptPassword(String arg0) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean promptPassphrase(String arg0) {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean promptYesNo(String arg0) {
            return true;
        }

        public void showMessage(String arg0) {
            System.out.println(arg0);
        }
    }
}
```

However one of the servers does not display the information. Instead it output's the command a bunch of times like so (it does this for any command not just df):

```
<SERVER NAME>

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k

df -k
```

All of the other servers output as you would expect with something like this:

```
<SERVER NAME>
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/zeus-root
                      322M  133M  173M  44% /
tmpfs                 943M     0  943M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                  938M  160K  938M   1% /dev
tmpfs                 943M     0  943M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             228M   16M  201M   8% /boot
/dev/mapper/zeus-home
                       58G  191M   55G   1% /home
/dev/mapper/zeus-tmp  368M   11M  339M   3% /tmp
/dev/mapper/zeus-usr  8.3G  544M  7.3G   7% /usr
/dev/mapper/zeus-var  2.8G  349M  2.3G  14% /var
/dev/sdb1             151G   97G   47G  68% /storage
```

The only difference between the server that is not functioning properly and the others is that the server is running Solaris 10 operating system.

Any ideas as to how I can fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: NB you should consider using an exec channel rather than a shell channel.

Comment: On the server that's misbehaving, could you figure out what process(es) are starting when this program connects and tries to run df? And check the /etc/passwd entry for the account you're logging into? My suspicion is that the account you're logging into may not have a normal shell.

Comment: `exec` channel is probably what you are after: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html  Here's an example using the `exec` channel that issues the `sudo` command on the remote host: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java.html